# atom text editor: autocomplete doesn't work

Tags: autocomplete, atom-editor

I started using atom IDE for writing HTML+ CSS code. 
autocomplete-atom-api is activated and still no code is completed neither automatically nor when I press ctrl+space.

This is my keymap.cson file:

```
'.active.pane':
  'ctrl-space': 'autocomplete:toggle'
```

Do you know what can be the problem?

Comment: Which version of Atom are you currently using?  I suspect you re using the wrong autocomplete package, the standard `autocomplete` package was deprecated in favour of the `autocomplete-plus` package which has support for HTML and CSS out of the box.  In theory it should be installed by default.

Answer (score 11):

The problem was resolved by Packages->Keybinding Resolver->toggle

Comment: for me, it's `Packages` > `Autocomplete Clang` > `Toggle`